# Xerces conflicts string.h

Tags: c++, xerces

Compiling my program I have this error:

```
/usr/include/xercesc/util/Compilers/GCCDefs.hpp:133:60: error: declaration of ‘int strcasecmp(const char*, const char*)’ has a different exception specifier
/usr/include/string.h:536:12: error: from previous declaration ‘int strcasecmp(const char*, const char*) throw ()’
make: *** [src/test/VFTImageMaterial.o] Error 1
```

Any idea about this conflict with string.h?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define HAVE_STRCASECMP. This probably should be defined automatically by ./configure in config.h - have you run ./configure?

Comment: I found the problem: my project is linked with a library compiled with xerces-c-3.1, but I was trying to compile with a different version.